# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES from adb install; using Java 6, Android 5.0.2

Tags: java, android, installation, adb, sign

I've followed the instructions here and elsewhere on creating a signed jar file and I'm still getting INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES when I try to install the signed .apk onto my LG-D415.
As noted, the signing algorithm seems to work better with Java 6. So I uninstalled all versions of Java other than that and made sure keytool and jarsigner were using Java 6.

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias TabletClient -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 20000
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore debug.keystore Release\TabletClient.apk TabletClient
zipalign -v 4 Release\TabletClient.apk Release\TabletClientZ.apk
adb install Release\TabletClientZ.apk
```

adb logcat shows:

```
W/PackageManager(  957): android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl272628750.tmp/base.apk
W/PackageManager(  957):        at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectCertificates(PackageParser.java:1108)
W/PackageManager(  957):        at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectCertificates(PackageParser.java:1035)
W/PackageManager(  957):        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:11848)
W/PackageManager(  957):        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.access$2500(PackageManagerService.java:273)
W/PackageManager(  957):        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$7.run(PackageManagerService.java:9770)
W/PackageManager(  957):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
W/PackageManager(  957):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/PackageManager(  957):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
W/PackageManager(  957):        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
W/PackageManager(  957):        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
W/PackageManager(  957): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not recognize a critical extension
W/PackageManager(  957):        at org.apache.harmony.security.utils.JarUtils.verifySignature(JarUtils.java:120)
W/PackageManager(  957):        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.verifyCertificate(JarVerifier.java:346)
W/PackageManager(  957):        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.readCertificates(JarVerifier.java:320)
W/PackageManager(  957):        at java.util.jar.StrictJarFile.<init>(StrictJarFile.java:68)
W/PackageManager(  957):        at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectCertificates(PackageParser.java:1050)
```

Any ideas? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. The .apk was being signed as part of the build in adt, but with a key that didn't work. For some reason the jarsigner step didn't completely replace the old signature, or show any error. So when the .apk was installed on the Android device it had a problem with the bad key.
The trick to finding this was to open the .apk file as a zip file before running jarsigner, and then delete the META-INF directory. jarsigner then created it correctly, with the key Android creates in the .android directory.
Once I realized this I was able to fix the problem by changing the adt command to use Android's key.

Comment: Could you paste the adt command that ended up fixing the problem?

Comment: Never mind, my solution was to add _signingConfig signingConfigs.release_ to my wear gradle release buildType.